# Dual display Psychtoolbox Matlab

Tags: matlab, multiple-monitors, psychtoolbox

I'm starting with Matlab, so doing the tuto from peterscarfe.com.
I have 2 screens on my computer, but when I run the first code of the tuto, it seems that it recognizes those 2 screens as one larger :

```
% Clear the workspace and the screen
sca;
close all;
clearvars;

% Here we call some default settings for setting up Psychtoolbox
PsychDefaultSetup(2);

% Get the screen numbers. This gives us a number for each of the screens
% attached to our computer.
screens = Screen('Screens');
```

with this code, screens=0, while i was expecting a vector [0 1] ? Because I would like to have my Matlab window on a screen, and my PTB one on the other...
I see there is the physicalDisplays to set in the screen function, but when I try with physicalDisplays=1, or just '1', it does not work, I don't know what kind of syntax is expected.
Thank you!

EDIT: sorry i forgot i’m on linux, ubuntu 16.04 .

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The behavior of Screen('Screens') can vary slightly between operating systems. The command you used, screens = Screen('Screens');, should return two screen values ([0 1]) as you were originally expecting. But, this can be more complex on a Linux system because more than one physical display can be part of one x-screen. I would try configuring your displays to be part of separate x-screens, for example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors

Comment: I used sudo NVidia settings, added a new screen (0 1) and it works, the problem was that the 2 screens were part of one! Thanks